# gmap api geocode zipcode saudi arabia not working as expected

Tags: json, google-maps, google-geocoder

Using Google Map API for getting the boundary and Coordinates for Zipcode.

While geocoding the Address for Saudi Arabia(SA) Region, when the Zipcode of Saudi Arabia(SA) is geocoded the Result of geocoder has address referring to **2517 The Hague, Netherlands**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "2517",
               "short_name" : "2517",
               "types" : [ "postal_code", "postal_code_prefix" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "The Hague",
               "short_name" : "The Hague",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "The Hague",
               "short_name" : "The Hague",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "South Holland",
               "short_name" : "ZH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Netherlands",
               "short_name" : "NL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "2517 The Hague, Netherlands",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.0958783,
                  "lng" : 4.3007563
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.0773935,
                  "lng" : 4.2732776
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.0847639,
               "lng" : 4.2801843
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.0958783,
                  "lng" : 4.3007563
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.0773935,
                  "lng" : 4.2732776
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJI9DHzc6wxUcR1s1th0GbWgQ",
         "types" : [ "postal_code", "postal_code_prefix" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "2517",
               "short_name" : "2517",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Russell Vale",
               "short_name" : "Russell Vale",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Wollongong City Council",
               "short_name" : "Wollongong",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New South Wales",
               "short_name" : "NSW",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Australia",
               "short_name" : "AU",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Russell Vale NSW 2517, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -34.3338503,
                  "lng" : 150.9245951
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -34.3654418,
                  "lng" : 150.8740632
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -34.3454996,
               "lng" : 150.9016476
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -34.3338503,
                  "lng" : 150.9245951
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -34.3654418,
                  "lng" : 150.8740632
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJSaEBIk8eE2sRQIa6P2t9ARw",
         "postcode_localities" : [ "Russell Vale", "Woonona" ],
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Since the results were not related to Saudi Arabia, added the **country** restrictions in the api. But it results has ***Partial Results*** value **True**, which refers the results are not accurate and it result has only the default value of Saudi Arabia location

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2517&components=country:SA

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Saudi Arabia",
               "short_name" : "SA",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Saudi Arabia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.1542839,
                  "lng" : 55.6666999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 16.379528,
                  "lng" : 34.5489978
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 23.885942,
               "lng" : 45.079162
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.1542839,
                  "lng" : 55.6666999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 16.379528,
                  "lng" : 34.5489978
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJQSqV5z-z5xURm7YawktQYFk",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But when the Address of Street/Region is added with Zipcode the geocode works
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2517+Ar+Riyadh&components=country:SA

Is there is way to force Gmap api to geocode the only with zipcode for the Saudi Arabia country  and result is accurate coordinates and Boundary?

Comment: Looks to me like the geocoder's database doesn't include 2517 as a valid zipcode/postal code for Saudi Arabia.  Is it a valid postal code (it doesn't look like it has enough digits to me)?  If so, you may need to go to Google Maps "mapmaker" and add it. (note: the ["working example"](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2517+Ar+Riyadh&components=country:SA) you posted returns postal code 55425)

Comment: Thanks
Please find the Zipcode of Saudi Arabia in the below link.
http://life-in-saudiarabia.blogspot.in/2015/09/zip-codepostal-code-of-major-cities-of.html#.V5g_BvnnZBc while using any of the Zipcode listed in this page the result from Google geocode is not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the postal code coverage is not quite good for Saudi Arabia.

You can search postal codes using a [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering), however often you get ZERO_RESULTS for missing postal codes.

For example,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A12631%7Ccountry%3ASA

returns a postal code, but

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A31433%7Ccountry%3ASA

returns ZERO_RESULTS.

For missing postal codes you can use the "Send Feedback" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Hope it helps!